# Python thread functionality - how do I implement?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I am new to Python threading and I have researched about it. I would like to implement the following functionality as written in pseudo code:

```
while True:
    while(file size < 1 GB):
        sleep for 1 minute
    process(file)
    file = next file
```

I want the process() function to be a daemon thread. The next time line 4 is reached in the code (next file is 1 GB), it should create a new thread if the previous thread is running. The maximum such threads are 3 and they loop one after the other. At any time there will be at least 2 threads free. So basically any one free thread should be called to do the job once the code reaches line 4.

Are daemon threads and thread queue the things I need to look at? Or is there some other way to solve this?